# I get the following error: java.lang.module.ResolutionException when importing a jar file into a new project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am working with IntelliJ, maven and javafx. I have written a sqlite wrapper also containing some javafx controls. This is the sqlite project, that I have exported into a jar file. The Package contains a main function, so I can test this jar file and it works fine.
Now I want to build a new Project using this wrapper. I opted for the quick and dirty solution, to copy the jar-file into my new Project folder, added a dependency in the pom-file and then imported a class of this module into the HelloController (the one automatically built by IntelliJ). IntelliJ helped me to add a required-line into module-info. Now I keep getting the following error:
java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Module xx.xxxx.sqlite contains package javafx.concurrent, module javafx.graphics exports package javafx.concurrent to xx.xxxx.sqlite

When reading other discussions I learned that this should be a split.package error, but I didn't really understand, what to do about it. I can neither remove the dependency from the sqlite project nor my new project, so what's the solution?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Would you be able to share your Project or the library?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see, what code to provide. I just reproduced the problem basically without any code of my own:
I created a javafx-application: in IntelliJ I clicked the button new project, selected JavaFX, gave it a name, selected language java, built system maven, gave it my own group id and left artifact as the project name.
In the project I created two classes: a class named Database, which is completely void and a class named Launch, with a main method referring to the main method of the HelloApplication (Without this one the jar won't find main).
Then I hit project structure in the file menu, went to artifacts and added jar from modules with dependencies.
Last I hit build artifacts.

After that I created another project exactly the same way.
I copied the jar file from the former project into a lib folder in the main directory of the new project. Then I added the following dependency into the pom-file:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>de.stefanpetersen</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqliteTest</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/sqliteTest.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

In the HelloController I imported

```
import de.stefanpetersen.sqlitetest.Database;
```

and added

Database db = new Database();

in the onHelloButtonClick-method.

IntelliJ told me to add

```
    requires de.stefanpetersen.sqlitetest;
```

in the module-info file.

When I try to run Launch I get the following error:

```
java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Module de.stefanpetersen.sqlitetest contains package javafx.scene.text, module javafx.graphics exports package javafx.scene.text to de.stefanpetersen.sqlitetest
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is solved. My error was to try the quick and dirty solution to copy the jar file into my new project.
The correct way is to use maven clean, install to write the jar file into my repositories instead. After that I removed the two lines 'scope' and 'systemPath' in the POM-file and everything worked fine.